# Sublime Text : how to detect coding errors (non existing variables...)

Tags: sublimetext3, jslint

I'm using Sublime Text and I'm fairly new to it.

I'd like to have my coding errors highlighted : missing semi colon, non existing variables...
But even installing the linters, Sublime Linter package and jslint and jshint, it doesn't work the way I want.

JSLint is way too strict: it was giving me errors for using tabs instead of spaces.

What I want is :

- errors about missing semi colons
- errors if I use a variable that I haven't defined anywhere

How can I do this ? I've checked before here on this forum, and on Google, but I haven't found anything :(

Nicolas.

Comment: I hope it will help you have a look at https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-catch-your-errors-in-sublime-text-3

Comment: thanks @pawansharma but I had checked this link before posting this question, and it didn't help me. Semi colon warnings work, but what I need is also an alert when I'm using a variable that is not defined.

Comment: Generally the various linters support an `rc` file that allows you to configure their settings.  For instance, eslint has a `.eslintrc`, jshint a `.jshintrc`, etc.  I assume there is such a thing for jslint as well.  It's a JSON file that you can set presets in-- for instance, you could set it to only complain for missing semicolons and globals.  I would recommend doing a little google search for that.  _**THAT SAID**_ -- make sure to weigh heavily if it is truly too restrictive-- if I remember correctly it adheres closely to Crockfords rules, which are pretty good...

Answer (score 1):

I think [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) will fit your needs. It's newer than jshint and jslint. 
You can read a comparison here: https://www.sitepoint.com/comparison-javascript-linting-tools/.
It's really flexible in specifying the linting rules.

> The primary reason ESLint was created was to allow developers to
>   create their own linting rules. ESLint is designed to have all rules
>   completely pluggable.

The rules that will help you with missing semicolons and undefined variables are [semi](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi) and [no-undef](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef).

You can use it in Sublime with the [SublimeLinter-eslint](https://github.com/roadhump/SublimeLinter-eslint) or [SublimeLinter-contrib-eslint_d](https://github.com/roadhump/SublimeLinter-contrib-eslint_d) plugin. The second one is faster, and it allows me to enable linting to be executed as I type.

Comment: ok thanks I'll try this as soon as possible (this is a side project so I don't work on it every day). When I try and validate your solution, I'll mark it as the correct answer